# Multiple Email Validation

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate multiple email addresses separated by commas or just one email address depending on the user entry.

I created this function:

```
function isEmailMultiple($address) 
        {
            $validate = array();
            if(strlen($address) < 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            $emailAddresses = explode(",", $address);
            foreach($emailAddresses as $emailAdd)
                {
                    $emailAdd = trim($emailAdd);
                    if (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])*(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])([a-z0-9])+)*$/i', $emailAdd))
                        {
                            // if validation fails, add error to array
                            $validate[$emailAdd] = 1;
                        }
                }

            if(count($validate) == 0)
                {
                    // No errors added to the array
                    return true;        
                } 

            else 
                {           
                    return false;
                }
        }
```

This is the implode function:

```
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $emailfromform) . "\r\n";
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in. . .
```

Comment: where have u used implode function? Post that code too

Comment: You should show the code that actually uses implode(). Additionally, the error message says it all. You need to make sure you pass the glue and an array to implode().

Comment: function isEmailMultiple($address) 
$address = array();
You override parameter. and use new variable as parameter in implode function
remove $address = array(); line and try again

Comment: check with var_dump($emailfromform); what it returns

Comment: Can you show the form field where the email addresses are added? Is it one field? Or multiple fields?

Comment: @JohnConde it is just one field.

Comment: @ThisBoyPerforms I made an answer I think addresses your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$emailfromform` is just one value (a string) you can't use `implode()` and it only accepts arrays (to turn them into a string).

Now if you are trying to make sure the email addresses are separated by a comma, you can try something like this:

```
// split email address by space, comma, colon, or semi-colon
$emailfromform = preg_split("/[\s,;:]+/", $emailfromform);
// Put them back together separated by a comma
$emailfromform = implode(",", $emailfromform);
// add to the headers
$headers .= 'BCC: '. $emailfromform . "\r\n";
```

Then to validate the email address just use a function like you had. Here's my version of what you wrote with some improvements:

```
function isEmailMultiple(array $emails) {
    if(count($emails) === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $emailAddresses = explode(",", $emails);
    foreach($emailAddresses as $emailAdd) {
        $emailAdd = trim($emailAdd);
        if (!filter_var($emailAdd, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how do I validate them?

Comment: Use your validate function. I added my version of it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isEmailMultiple($address)
$address = array();
```

You override parameter. and use new variable as parameter in implode function

Remove `$address = array();` line and try again